# Disable External Content loaded from Wordpress Plugins

Tags: wordpress

The Websites of my clients use Wordpress Plugins, that load external Content like Google Fonts, which Violates the GDPR (General Data Protection Regulation). I am trying to find a way to comply with the GDPR.

I tried disabling or uninstalling the plugins, whcih only worked for a few Cases. Most often doing this broke the website.

Adding a local Copy of the external content, only works for Plugins where I can change the reference to the content.

So there are still plugins that are in violation with the GDPR and I have no effective way to deal with them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin that can search for all google fonts and install them locally: https://wordpress.org/plugins/local-google-fonts/